# Is cmd.exe of Windows 7 capable of displaying the degree character '°'?

Tags: windows, command-line, character-encoding, fonts

Is cmd.exe of Windows 7 capable of displaying the degree character '°'?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol
http://ascii-table.com/ansi-codes.php

Answer (score 4):

Works for me. I don't see why it wouldn't work. Did you try it? If so, post the code you used, there may be a problem in the code itself.

I just used an `echo` command to test it:

```
> ECHO °
°
```

Answer (score 3):

`cmd.exe` is capable of it; however, the Windows Console might not: by default it uses the system's "OEM" codepage (`cp775`, for example - see `chcp`), and Unicode (`chcp 65001`) is incredibly flaky (well, on XP at least).

Answer (score 3):

At the prompt, hold down the Alt key and type 0176 on your numeric keypad. When you release the Alt key, a degree symbol should be displayed.